# Open a modal windows with jQuery, content provided by the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, modal-dialog

I'm creating an ASP.Net MVC website. I've to display some text in some modal windows. I found several plugins of jQuery which makes a modal windows, but the content is generated on the client.

I need to call the server, e.g. when I've to display my modal windows, got to the server and load the page X-Y-Z as content of the modal windows.

If I can customize the modal windows(The goal is to have the possibility to have non-rectangle modal windows.

I searched some plugins of this kind, but for now I found only modal windows with javascript content.

Do you know one pluging which does  this?

In addition, it seems that the plugin subdomain of jquery is down :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at jQuery [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Something like this will give you want you want:

**HTML**

```
<a href="your-page" id="ModalDialogOpenLink">open</a>
<div id="ModalDialogDiv"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#ModalDialogOpenLink').click(function () {
    $('#ModalDialogDiv').load(this.href, function () {
        $(this).dialog();
    });
    return false;
});
```

**Edit** I've added the html markup as well.

Comment: Thank you, I will finally use the windows in the kendo UI interface